# New CentOS server VPS deployed - IP address doesn't load website

Tags: centos7, vps, website

I've setup a brand new VPS server and installed CentOS 7 and Webmin to setup a webserver. I've installed Apache, BIND, setup the DNS started Apache, put html files in document root folder public_html and when I visit the IP address for the server, no website loads. The page just times out. Can someone please help me to get this website loading. Next I'll configure the FQDN to this server to serve up the website. What did I miss or what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thanks for the comment. Is it the firewall on the server or client? I have a firewall on both but disabled my local firewall. Can you provide some insight into configuring the firewall so the IP address loads the website?

Comment: No, I have no way to do any of those since I know nothing about your firewalls. You have to talk to your hoster and figure it out yourself.

Comment: CentOS 7 is almost EOL, which means that almost all software will be both really old (think versions that were already slightly behind the latest and greatest in 2014 )  and at best the OS will only get get updates for the most critical security vulnerabilities but nothing more. The only reason to install that version now, is to test your migrations away from CentOS 7- That is not the server OS that you want to spend a lot of effort on.